# Delete query is taking too much time in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am having a table XXXX . in which total records are 6 , On the same table XXXX I am running a query
`delete from XXXX where id="6cb1e00e-259f-4e58-ad7f-79aec7cbda14";`

It's taking 20-30 minutes even after that , I am not able to get response of success or failure . id is the primary key of table . Need an advice on the same . Thanks in advance .

One more key point , I want to let you know that `SHOW OPEN TABLES;` continuously shows the table XXXX `In_use:1`

Technical Info :
Mysql 8 .

OS:Ubuntu 18.04

DB Engine: InnoDB

Comment: Please check if the table is locked by some transaction. Use SHOW OPEN TABLES command.

Comment: @AmitVerma Basically I am running this query as the first one from mysql CLI after `sudo service mysql restart` . So no doubt that lock may be by any other transaction

Comment: An check whether the column In_use is greater than 0. In that case, the table is locked. you need to kill the process which has locked it.

Comment: @AmitVerma  Yes It is `In_use:1`;

Comment: Are there any triggers on this table?

Comment: @BillKarwin  no triggers are there

Comment: one more point `sudo service mysql restart` is also taking too much time .